# Getting a iPhone OS 2.2.1 app approved after the OS 3.0 release

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-2.2.1

I’m writing a new iPhone app which doesn’t depend on any of the 3.0 APIs.  2.2.1 should work fine and has a substantially larger user base currently and in the *near* future as last I checked Apple was expecting iPod Touch owners to cough up $10 to upgrade to 3.0.  That leaves a nontrivial number of cheap users who will stay with 2.2.1 as long as they can.

So my goal is to build and release this app using 2.2.1.  I know that all app store submissions must run on 3.0, and I plan to do plenty of testing on 3.0.  The language on the [iPhone OS 3.0 Readiness Checklist](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/checklist/) leaves me optimistic, but will Apple continue to accept 2.2.1 app submissions (and for how long?), or will they laugh manically and reject any 2.2.1 apps simply to force 3.0?

**The main question:**

Has anyone on SO released a 2.2.1 compatible app after 3.0 was released and had it accepted (or explicitly rejected with 3.0 being the reason)?

Comment: You might actually be surprised at the 3.0 uptake rate: http://tapbots.com/blog/news/iphone-os-30-adoption-rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own app (Task Coach) was built for 2.2.1 (on the 3.0 SDK, but that's irrelevant) and was approved last week, so go for it.

Answer (score 2):

You must test it against both 2.2.1 and 3.0 then I can't see any problems - but I wouldn't assume it will work with both - you must test!

Answer (score 1):

They won't reject a 2.2.1 app unless it fails during 3.0 testing. You should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

Why would they ever stop supporting apps that run in 2.2.1, provided they run in 3.0? You are just not taking advantage of new features, not building a fundamentally different app.

Answer (score 0):

well now it has changed a little. New apps usually come only for iphone OS 3.0 as well as other iphone OS 3.0 approved apps that now longer support 2.2.1 so like for my reson i need the iphone 3.0 software update for ipod touch as for almost every app i want to get doesn't support 2.2.1